# template parameter is ambiguous / deduced conflicting types for parameter

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, c++14

The program below generates a compiler error:

- MSVC: error C2782: 'double dot(const V &,const V &)': template parameter 'V' is ambiguous
- GCC:  deduced conflicting types for parameter 'const V' ('Matrix<3, 1>' and 'UnitVector')

I had thought that it would not have this problem because the constructor `UnitVector(Vector)` is marked `explicit`, and therefore the arguments (of the call to `dot()`) can only resolve as `Vector` with implicit conversions. Can you tell me what I am misunderstanding? Does the compiler consider `explicit` constructors as implicit conversions when resolving template parameters?

```
template<int M, int N>
struct Matrix {
};

using Vector = Matrix<3,1>;

struct UnitVector : Vector{
    UnitVector(){}
    explicit UnitVector(const Vector& v)
    {}

    operator const Vector&(){
        return *static_cast<const Vector*>(this);
    }
};

template<typename V>
double dot(const V& a, const V& b){
    return 0.0;
}

int main()
{
    dot(Vector(),UnitVector());
}
```

Comment: No, I fear the compiler (the language) isn't so sophisticated: It needs to deduce the same type of `V` from objects of different types, so you get an ambiguity error.

Answer (score 0):

No, that does not work. But actually, you don't need the template

```cpp
double dot(const Vector &, const Vector &) {...}
```

works. You don't even need the conversion operator defined in `UnitVector`. Child to base conversions are done implicitly.

If you want to generally take two types that are implicitly convertible to a common type, the following should work (untested)

```cpp
template<class U>
double dot_impl(const U&, const U&) {...}

template<class U, class V>
auto dot(const U &u, const V &v) {
    return dot_impl<std::common_type_t<U, V>>(u, v);
}
```

Since the template parameter is explicit, the implicit conversions to thw common type of those two are done in the call, so everything works nice. I moved the original `dot` to `dot_impl`, since otherwise we would call `dot` with one template parameter, which could still be ambiguous.

Comment: The code in my question was extracted from a larger program to test the error. There are very many other instantiations of the template.

Comment: But you're right about the child to base conversion, of course..

Comment: @Museful I updated my answer so it should provide what you need.